# ASP.NET, how to show the error message of customValidator without postback?

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to show the error message of customValidator without POSTBACK?

I have used both requiredFieldValidator and customValidator. The fomer can be inline and can show error message without postback. Is this possible for customValidator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Update Panel ajax to this action without postback.

Answer (score 1):

***Option 1 :***

Whenever I create a custom validator, I try to create a server and **client side validation methods** to validate. creating a client side method will avoid unnecessary postback. As a safety measure, server side method should be present.

Example :

```
<asp:Textbox id="text1" runat="server" text=""></asp:Textbox>
<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator2" runat="server" 
  ControlToValidate = "text1"
  ErrorMessage = "You must enter at least 8 characters!"
  ClientValidationFunction="validateLength" >
</asp:CustomValidator>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validateLength(oSrc, args){
   args.IsValid = (args.Value.length >= 8);
}
</script>
```

***Option 2:***

It is not always possible to build a client side validation method. There you can **use update panel** to hide those postbacks.

Comment: good answer.  On a related note, with all the Reuse and OOP going on out there why do we have to do the exact same thing in two ( three if you count the database constraints) places?

Comment: Database constraints are for database consistency. They should always be there because you never know from where the data will come into database. WebService, Website, Manually, etc.   Server side should also always be there because no one can tamper with it. It makes your application robust.  Client side is just something you do optionally to improve user experience.

Comment: I'm now imaging myself in a status meeting with the Board/CTO trying to explain why 'validation' was 'done 100%' six months ago but three of the top developers are still billing hours to the charge code.

Comment: And besides, a custom piece of c# or any server side code can not be directly resolved to javascript or sql (except for Entity Framework). Hence no reuse.

Comment: Why can't the database constraint exception bubble up and be used in the middle tier to signal an invalid input?

Comment: Yes they can. In Fact that's how it should be done for database validations. But just with this fact, you can't skip server side validations. Take the above example, just to avoid accepting a string more than 8 characters, why would you cause a database round trip. You can easily take care of it on server or client side and it will make the postback very fast. Database calls are slow.

Comment: At the same time, having the 8 character constraint in database will be considered a good practice. So that if the data comes from any other source, it will still be consistent.

Comment: OK , so the Board can be told we are tripling the hours/cost for validation programming because of a need for speed.  I'll buy that.